# In C++, what is the most efficient way in defining a very simple object

Tags: c++, class, struct

Suppose I am defining a surface object

```
class surface
{
private:
    vector<point> points_;
    vector<hexFace> hexFaces_;
}
```

I have already written a `point` class, which is very necessary, but as for `hexFace`, actually it is very simple, it is just a list of four point **labels**, that is int[4]. And I don't need to do any complex operation on it.

So my question is: what is the most efficient way in defining such an `hexFace` object. Should I use struct, or I'd better go with a class or anything else? What would you do? Thanks

And if I need to go with class, can I defining another class in the current class in a nesting way? If I can, do I have to write its constructors within this file also?

Does a struct need a constructor to initialize it?

Comment: You misspelled the `class` keyword.

Comment: There's no performance difference between `struct` and `class`.

Comment: struct's and classes are equivalent in all regards except in their declaration (structs default to public, classes default to private)

Comment: Yes, use inner classes/structs. And yes, you can define constructors and methods for inner classes in the same header and compilation unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask several questions:

> *what is the most efficient way in defining such an hexFace object.*

Run-time efficiency will be about the same for any solution you choose. Lines-of-code efficiency, or maintainer-programmer-brain-power efficiency is probably more valuable.

If you are limited to pre-C++11 features, I'd use:

```
struct hexFace {
  int labels_[4];
};
```

If you can use C++11 features, try:

```
class surface
{
private:
    std::vector<point> points_;
    std::vector<std::array<int, 4>> hexFaces_;
}
```

> *Should I use struct, or I'd better go with a class or anything else?*

`struct` and `class` are nearly synonymous. Use whichever you think expresses your intent more clearly. As for "something else", try `std::array`

> *can I defining another class in the current class in a nesting way?*

Yes, you can. Try:

```
class surface
{
private:
    class hexFace { public: int lables[4]; };
    vector<point> points_;
    vector<hexFace> hexFaces_;
};
```

> *If I can, do I have to write its constructors within this file also?*

You may, or you may choose to write it elsewhere, or you may choose to omit the user-defined constructor altogether.

Here is how to write it inline:

```
class surface {
public:
    class hexFace { public: hexFace() { std::cout << "inline constructor!\n" } };
}
```

Here is how to write it externally

```
class surface {
  public:
  class hexFace {
    public:
      hexFace();
  };

// in another file ...
surface::hexFace::hexFace() { std::cout << "extern constructor\n"; }
```

> *Does a struct need a constructor to initialize it?*

Neither a `class` nor a `struct` require a user-defined constructor, but both allow them.

```
struct X {
  X() { std::cout << "in struct constructor!\n"; }
};
class Y {
  public: 
    Y() { std::cout << "in class constructor!\n"; }
};
```

Comment: Okay, for convenience of further maintenance, I will write an external class. By the way, can a class without having a cpp file if I declare all the constructors and member functions as inline?

Comment: Yes, you do not need a CPP file if all of the member functions (including the constructor) are defined in the header file.